# NoneType Error even though attribute is defined?

Tags: python, excel, vba, win32com

im getting this error on line 15 and I cant figure out why. any ideas? it appears that the attributes are clearly defined so I'm at a complete loss. any help would be much appreciated.
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'Sheets'

```
import win32com.client
import openpyxl
import shutil
import os, subprocess

def Inny_Outy():
    input = 'C:/Users/tyler/Desktop/Beef web/Queue'
    output = 'C:/Users/tyler/Desktop/Beef web/Finished'

    for filename in os.listdir(input):
        xl=win32com.client.Dispatch('Excel.Application')
        ini=xl.Workbooks.Open(input + '/' + filename)
        inb=xl.Workbooks.Open('C:/Users/tyler/Desktop/Beef Web/Export.xlsx')
        ini.Sheets('Sheet1').Range('A2:K100000').Copy()
        inb.Sheets('Export').Paste(inb.Sheets('Export').Range('A2'))
        inb.Close(True)
        ini.Close(True)
        CopyIn_run_macros()
        Out=xl.Workbooks.Open('C:/Users/tyler/Desktop/Beef Web/Finish.xlsx')
        add = ini.Sheets.Add(Before = None , After = ini.Sheets(ini.Sheets.count))
        add.Name = "E1"
        add.Name = "231"
        add.Name = "BIMgen"
        Out.Sheets('E1').Range('A1:T100000').Copy()
        ini.Sheets('E1').Paste(ini.Sheets('E1').Range('A1'))
        Out.Sheets('BIMgen').Range('A1:H100000').Copy()
        ini.Sheets('BIMgen').Paste(ini.Sheets('BIMgen').Range('A1'))
        Out.Sheets('231').Range('A1:AG100000').Copy()
        ini.Sheets('231').Paste(ini.Sheets('231').Range('A1'))
        ini.Close(True)
        Out.Close(True)
        shutil.move(input + '/' + filename, output)

def CopyIn_run_macros():
    #Run macros
    xl=win32com.client.Dispatch('Excel.Application')
    BC=xl.Workbooks.Open('C:/Users/tyler/Desktop/Beef Web/Wall Types Live.xlsm')
    xl.Application.Run('Python2')
    EXP=xl.Workbooks.Open('C:/Users/tyler/Desktop/Beef Web/Export.xlsx')
    print("Importing Export To BeefCake....")
    EXP.Sheets('Export').Range('A2:K100000').Copy()
    BC.Sheets('Raw Export').Paste(BC.Sheets('Raw Export').Range('A12'))
    EXP.Close(True)
    print("Complete.")
    print("Running Macros....")
    xl.Application.Run('Python')
    print("Complete.")
    print("Exporting BeefCake Data....")
    FIN=xl.Workbooks.Open('C:/Users/tyler/Desktop/Beef Web/Finish.xlsx')
    BC.Sheets('E1 Final').Range('A1:T100000').Copy()
    FIN.Sheets('E1').Paste(FIN.Sheets('E1').Range('A1'))
    BC.Sheets('BIMgen 2.0').Range('A1:H100000').Copy()
    FIN.Sheets('BIMgen').Paste(FIN.Sheets('BIMgen').Range('A1'))
    BC.Sheets('Goodall Build').Range('A1:AG100000').Copy()
    FIN.Sheets('231').Paste(FIN.Sheets('231').Range('A1'))
    FIN.Close(True)
    print("Complete.")
    del xl

Inny_Outy()
```

Comment: Line 15 being `ini.Close(True)` ?

Comment: `xl.Workbooks.Open()` must be encountering a file it can't open, and therefore it returns a `None` value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        inb=xl.Workbooks.Open('C:/Users/tyler/Desktop/Beef Web/Export.xlsx')
```

I would guess that this is returning None because the file doesn't exist, or something got messed up with the directory.

Comment: @Stanford Basset I just double checked the directory and the file and its correct. any other ideas? this has honestly got me stumped.

Comment: ini=xl.Workbooks.Open(input + '/' + filename) seems to be working normally. I'd try troubleshooting (i.e. printing the value of ini to see what it is there, or trying to use that format on the Export.xlsx file), and see if you can figure out what's making the one work and not the other.

Comment: If it's the formatting that's causing the issue, that's one thing, but it might be the file itself that's causing the issue, and that's a different problem.

Comment: @Stanford Basset Found it! The sheet I was trying to run through and the sheet I was pasting to had the same name. lol. works now. thank you so much.

Comment: Ah yes.. Excel is notoriously incapable of opening two files that have the same name... :P